# Combobox DataBinding Bug - Won't write value if programmatically losing focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a blank form, to which I've added a default `ComboBox`, `TextBox` (just for receiving focus), and `Label`.  The combobox has a databinding set up to a private property on the form.

**Setup:**

```vb
Private Sub FormLoad(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
      Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim data = {New With {.Display = "", .Value = ""},
                New With {.Display = "A", .Value = "A"},
                New With {.Display = "B", .Value = "B"},
                New With {.Display = "C", .Value = "C"}}

    ComboBox1.DataSource = data
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", someClass, "SomeProperty")
End Sub
```

Where someClass is a private variable of type `SomeClass` below:

```vb
Public Class SomeClass

    Private _someProperty As String = ""

    Public Property SomeProperty() As String
        Get
            Return _someProperty
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _someProperty = value
            Form1.Label1.Text = String.Format("Some property = ""{0}""", value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Expected Behavior:**

The default [`Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) is that changes will be propagated `OnValidation`.

If I select a value from the `ComboBox` and then click off it onto the `TextBox`, then the DataBinding will write the new value to the specified property and the Label on my main form will be updated.

**Possible Bug:**

The problem comes in because we have a business rule that requires us to perform validation immediately when a selection is made.  In order for validation to fire, the ComboBox has to lose focus, so by adding the following code to the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event, we can programmatically force validation

```vb
Private Sub ComboChanged(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

The problem is that this breaks the databinding for the very first selection.  The combobox has definitely lost focus, it definitely has a new `SelectedValue` and validation has definitely fired, but the databinding did not write the new value to `SomeProperty` on `someClass` (The setter never fires and the label, in this example, doesn't update).  In subsequent selections, the setter will fire

If necessary, from the `ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted` event, I'll manually write the databinding, but feel like this is extra work since I need to process code during the Validation Event as well.

```vb
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Item("SelectedValue").WriteValue()
```

**Questions:**

- *Shouldn't programmatically and manually losing focus do the same thing?*
- *Why does this work on subsequent selections, but not on the first one?*
- *Is this in fact some bug in WinForms, or have i done something horribly wrong?*

**Update:**

Thanks for the answers so far.  I guess I was looking more for an explanation than a workaround.  Why would it be the case that a bound property that updates on validation doesn't update even when the control has validated.  Further, why would it not happen the first time, but work for all future events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set this up differently. You really shouldn't be changing your UI from your `SomeClass` object. It should just store data:

```
Public Class SomeClass

    Private _someProperty As String = ""

    Public Property SomeProperty() As String
        Get
            Return _someProperty
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _someProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then, change your FormLoad and fix your data bindings so that everything is data bound:

```
Private Sub FormLoad(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
      Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim data = {New With {.Display = "", .Value = ""},
                New With {.Display = "A", .Value = "A"},
                New With {.Display = "B", .Value = "B"},
                New With {.Display = "C", .Value = "C"}}

    Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", someClass, "SomeProperty");

    ComboBox1.DataSource = data
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", someClass, "SomeProperty", 
          false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
End Sub
```

Notice that above we bind `someClass` to your Label so that when the combobox is changed, the label will be updated.

The final bit is to set the `DataSourceUpdateMode` on your combobox to OnPropertyChanged which will allow you to get rid of that event handler.

Better still, you should have `SomeClass` inherit from [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) because you are data binding it and you want to make sure that changes to SomeClass will have it notify the UI.

Comment: Thanks, the label text update is just me being lazy for this sample code, but isn't on the actual codebase.

Comment: I'm running into the problem where we have some IsDirty logic that fires during the Validated event.  When I use the `OnPropertyChanged` `DataSourceUpdateMode`, then the new property  value is definitely written (which is good), but it isn't updated until after the validation has been performed, so the IsDirty validation checks come up empty even though the value has (will eventually) change.

Comment: @KyleMit, that's another reason to have your underling data object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Instead of trapping the Validated event to handle IsDirty, you should instead handle the `PropertyChanged` event of your data object.

Answer (score 1):

I can't honestly answer questions 1 and 2, but I can give you this to answer question 3. You didn't do anything terribly wrong, just didn't include a helpful line of code.

Add the following line to `FormLoad`:

```
ComboBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
```

I tested this out in Visual Studio 2010 and the label updates properly when a new value is selected from the `combobox`.